# Unable to view .pages file in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I'm loading a Test.pages file in my UIWebView which is called `myUniqueWebView` in my app but I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

I'm using this code

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

And this code in the `viewDidLoad`

```
[self loadDocument:@"Test.pages" inView:self.myUniqueWebView];
```

Any ideas why it's not working? I'm testing it on my device. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"pages"];
```

isn't working and if I zip the file it just loads an empty UIWebView

Comment: Have you tried with `pathForResource:@"Test" ofType: @"pages"]`

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the path variable, sinds it seems be `nil` as specified by the error.

Comment: Emm, well, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried everything and only succeeded in viewing PDF files. That's very disappointing, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It might be your [answer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html). But seems like you have to compress it to view the file in the UIWebView.

Comment: Well, it does load my view now, if I zip the file, but it just loads an empty UIWebView, what can be wrong this time?

Comment: Not sure what is happening without the actual code that you have there. However, since the filetype is a mime type so you can check this method of UIWebView
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL